# How reliable is @Singleton?

Tags: scala, playframework

My Play application contains the following code:

```
@Singleton
class Application extends Controller {

  val followUpSchedule = system.scheduler.schedule(
    initialDelay = getMillisUntilNext5pm.milliseconds,
    interval = 1.day,
    receiver = followUpActor,
    message = FollowUpActor.SendFollowUps
  )
```

It seems (at least to me) that code will send the message to the Actor exactly once a day, right around 5pm.

However, sometime, it sends two. That is, sometime when I start up the server, the message will be sent twice every day.

Where would I start looking for the problem?

Comment: Can you change Application to `object Application`? Then there's only one instance as per scala.

Comment: @NKijak -- The code is somewhat simplified.  It's a class because I need Play to inject some dependencies when it's instantiated.

Comment: Another solution would be to have your actor store last send time and persist that somewhere.  Do you only have a single instance of the server running? Not clustered, or fail over, or anything of that sort?

Comment: @NKijak -- my question is not about adapting to the problem I have observed.  I am going to compensate for the multiple-thread challenge anyway, exactly so I can run redundant systems, but I want to know why it happened in this case.